# Change <href> to <script> javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, href

How do you make this href thing into a script so that it is executed immediately when you enter the webpage?

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='block';document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='block';">Click Here</a>
<div id="underlay">
</div>
<div id="lightbox">
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='none';">Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `<script>` tag at the end of the body.

You can also place it in the head, although it has to wait until the page loads:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='block';
}, false);
</script>
```